# Hover on mouse-over, un-hover on mouse-out of parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

In my trivial example below, I would like to have the solid blue div grow on mouse-over, but to preserve this state as long as the cursor is inside the orange box.

Once the cursor leaves the orange box, the solid blue box should collapse. The orange box represents a row in a list.

The real implementation is in a tool-tip-like slide-out on a complex row full of other details.

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

.row div {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.row .right {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
  width: 10px;
}

.row .right:hover {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Of course, this can easily be accomplished with JavaScript (which is how it is currently implemented):

```js
let right = $('.right');

right.mouseenter(() => right.addClass('hover'))

$('.row').mouseleave(() => right.removeClass('hover'))
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

.row div {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.row .right {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
  width: 10px;
}

.row .right.hover {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

But I would like, if possible, to use **a purely CSS approach** for reasons of code readability, performance and maintainability.

If it is in fact impossible, I will accept that as an answer.

The current implementation is in an Angular4 template, so we need to pepper the templates with directives like `(mouseleave)="tooltipElement && hideTooltip($event.target.children)` which seem like they should be unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses a little hack to simulate the *preserve hover state* thing. It does not keep it forever but for the duration you define as animation-delay. Probably 10 minutes of hovering is like forever in most scenarios, if you want to make it last longer you would just have to increase the number in the code below.

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

.row div {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.row .right {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: width 0.5s ease 600s;
  width: 10px; /* Unfortunately, this has to be 'different' from ... */
}

.row .right:hover {
  width: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.row:not(:hover) .right {
  width: 10.01px; /* ... this width. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/43393653 */
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Marvin. I edited my question to provide more detail on my problem. I would need the solid blue box to collapse once the cursor leaves the orange bounding box because it is actually a row in a list (hence `.row`). Currently, at least in my browser, it doesn't collapse (ever).

Comment: Oh, I'll have a look at it. Just tested it in Firefox where it shows the expected behaviour.

Comment: You're right! That's intriguing. I should have mentioned that I'm in the usually-enviable position of only supporting Chrome. If you change your answer, post another or at least preserve this answer, since it's useful for FF-only.

Comment: I've found the line that causes it to fail in Chrome. I'll update my answer as soon as I made it work in every browser.

Comment: This technique is very interesting. However, it's a trick, but my upvote for a very creative solution. As I said on my answer detecting certain conditions is impossible pure CSS, but brains can do anything!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thank you. In the beginning I also thought it would not be possible, but I'm seldom satisfied with such an answer :P msanford: It should now work in FF and Chrome. I'm not sure about the part with the comments behind, maybe I'll be able to figure out the reason for this behaviour (and maybe find a more 'clean' way to solve this than using double values). I'll leave a comment under your question when I come back to this again in the future (not sure if you get notified about edits).

Comment: I can't understand why it needs `10.01px`, or different values as you said. Can you explain?

Comment: Marvin, it does! And I'm similarly not satisfied with that. Especially in a list with, say, thousands of rows, having two event listeners attached to every row just rubbed me the wrong way. I'm sharing it with the team. Thanks!

Comment: This trick is always worth an upvote whenever it pops up. Incidentally, @msanford, you could have achieved it with a single event listener on the parent element, rather than 2 for each row: https://jsfiddle.net/petershaggynoble/cbhqaj9x/

Comment: @Shaggy I saw it during a code review. But thanks for the fiddle, I'll pass that around, too. Coming from a few years in the back-end so all these refreshers are very handy.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I couldn't figure it out, so I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43393653/3162554). Hopefully someone will provide an answer as I'm really interested in understanding this behaviour.

Comment: I've started a bounty there, it's a very interesting question

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS you can't do exactly what you are describing. You can make the blue border grows when you hover the row but not when you hover the blue element and preserve while is hovering on the row.

So you can hover the row and apply to the right element, and if it fits with your requirements will be as this:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

.row div {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.row .right {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
  width: 10px;
}

.row:hover  .right{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos. I edited my question to provide more detail on the problem.

Comment: Ok, I think the only approach that you will obtain is the @Marvin answer. That's a nice answer with a creative technique, so I recommend you to catch it and don't waste more time :D

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to in-line [the single-listener solution](https://jsfiddle.net/petershaggynoble/cbhqaj9x/) proposed by [@Shaggy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4768433/shaggy) in a comment above, for those cases when having event listeners might actually be fine.

```js
{
    let current=0;
    document.getElementById("group").addEventListener("mouseover",event=>{
        let target=event.target;
        if(target.classList.contains("right"))
            (current=target).classList.add("hover");
        else if(target===event.currentTarget&&current){
            current.classList.remove("hover");
            current=0;
        }
    },0)
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:20px;
}
#group{
  border:1px solid #999;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px 20px 0;
}
.row{
  border:1px solid #f90;
  display:block;
  height:20%;
  margin:0 0 20px;
  padding:20px;
  width:400px;
}
.row>div{
  border:1px dashed #00f;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  width:100px;
}
.row>.right{
  background:#00f;
  padding:20px 0;
  transition:width .5s ease;
  width:10px;
}
.row>.right.hover{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="group">
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
</div>
```